# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web App keeps starting IISExpress instead of Kestrel even though IISExpress settings are removed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis-express, kestrel-http-server

Every time I keep starting my ASP.NET Core Web App, it keeps starting IISExpress. I click DEBUG (or F5) and i noticed the little IISExpress systray icon show. I then manually exit it. Also, None of the debug (start/stop/pause) buttons are displayed .. so it's like it's not start-debugging .. but start-running.

target framework: .NETCore 2.1

Here's my files:-

```
launchSettings.json

{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Kestrel - Accounts.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}"
    }
  }
}
```

and here's the project in the solution:

[image]

Another interesting thing to note, if I try and hit the localhost website (the port is some random port, not `5000`) the site <s>never comes up</s> eventually starts up ... and this is a simple basic site.

Can anyone suggest where I should look/fix, please?

#### UPDATE

I can run the website 100% fine if i use the CLI. E.g.:

- (in the folder of the `.csproj`)
- `dotnet build`
- `dotnet publish -c DEBUG -o /app`
- `dotenet c:\app\Accounts.Api.dll`

.. and it runs fine with normal stuff outputed to the console...

Answer (score 0):

OK - weird. So I ended up doing the following:

- removing project from solution.
- re-adding the project back to the solution

and now it works!

go figure :/

Comment: Then it seems to be cached in the memory when the solution is loaded.

Comment: Ah! I can't remember if i killed VS2017 and then re-opened it _and_ the problem still existed, before I stumbled across my fix.